# Rails post xml to iframe

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3, post, iframe

I'm working with third party that requires I post xml to an iframe. I was originally trying to use the data URI, but this seemed like a poor approach all together. From my understanding data URI is not IE compatible and is not suitable for longer documents. I have started implementing a java approach but was wondering if anyone had done something similar using Rails or if anyone saw any advantages to doing so.

Comment: How on Earth do you link cross browser issues to Java?

Comment: @Tom Apologies for the misstatement. I clarified my post. I was originally using data URI, which does have cross browser issues. I am mostly interested in learning if folks think there is an advantage to using java or ruby to make the post.